# Why does EF retrieve IDs unnecessarily when doing a one-to-many join?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Suppose you have an `Author` domain class, and a `Book` domain class and each `Author` can have 0 or more `Books` (a one-to-many relationship).

If you do the following:

```
var dtos = dbContext.Authors.Select(a => new
{
    Name = a.Name,
    BookNames = a.Books.Select(b => b.Name).ToList() 
}).ToList();
```

You expect the following SQL to get generated since you only requested the names of the authors, and the names of the books of each author:

```
SELECT [a].[Name], [b].[Name]
FROM [Authors] AS [a]
LEFT JOIN [Books] AS [b] ON [a].[Id] = [b].[AuthorId]
ORDER BY [a].[Id], [b].[Id]
```

However, instead, Entity Framework causes the following SQL to be generated:

```
SELECT [a].[Name], [a].[Id], [b].[Name], [b].[Id]
FROM [Authors] AS [a]
LEFT JOIN [Books] AS [b] ON [a].[Id] = [b].[AuthorId]
ORDER BY [a].[Id], [b].[Id]
```

which apparently is unnecessarily retrieving the IDs of all authors and the IDs of all their books.

This is while this doesn't happen when you do the joining from the other side, that is, from books to authors. For example, when you request the names of the books, and the names of their authors, like:

```
var dtos = dbContext.Books.Select(b => new
{
    Name = b.Name,
    BookNames = b.Author == null ? null : b.Author.Name
}).ToList();
```

The generated SQL for the above code would be:

```
SELECT [b].[Name], CASE
    WHEN [a].[Id] IS NULL THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
    ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
END, [a].[Name]
FROM [Books] AS [b]
LEFT JOIN [Authors] AS [a] ON [b].[AuthorId] = [a].[Id]
```

which is not retrieving the IDs, as expected.

Why is this the case? Why does EF Core retrieve the IDs even though I didn't include them in my projection?

I have tested this with EF Core 3.x + 5.0 RC1. If that matters.

Comment: At a guess, object / change tracking

Comment: @Diado There is no object to track, because the entity is not selected, but an anonymous object containing only the names.

Comment: Good point, didn't spot that.

Comment: If you think about it, you aren't asking for flat Author, BookName pairs. You're asking for *one* Author name with multiple books. There's no way EF can generate that hierarchy without the PK values. Nothing prevents multiple authors from having the same name

Comment: `when you request the names of the books, and the names of their authors.` what query did you use? `db.Books.Select(b=>{b.BookName,b.Author.AuthorName})` would return author names multiple times too

Comment: And how do you know which book belongs to which author?

Comment: The second query is *very* different and doesn't need the IDs. There's only one possible AuthorName per Book. Even so, a check for `Author.ID` is made to ensure any possible `NULL`s are produced by the join

Comment: @Klamsi How does retrieving the IDs of books and authors separately help though? Say you have a list of 10 authors with their IDs and a list of 20 books with their IDs, now, how would you know which book belongs to which author? IDs are useless in that case, if that was EF's purpose, it should have retrieved the `AuthorId` FK column on the books, not the `Id` PK column.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Well, that's true, but my question wasn't about multiple author names being returned.

Comment: "it should have retrieved the AuthorId FK column on the books." This is the id column of the author in the result line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The SQL query result set is flat. The one you expect would have been generated (and indeed is generated when you doing it from other side) if your query was flat as well, like this

```
var query =
    from a in dbContext.Authors
    from b in a.Books.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new { Name = a.Name, BookName = b.Name };
```

However your query result shape is different - name + correlated **list** of book names. In general SQL cannot provide such shape, so EF Core should somehow convert (group) the returned flat result set client side. The records come ordered by the two ids, but these two ids are also needed for correct grouping. Well, technically speaking, all ids except the last in order, so `[b].[Id]` in this case is redundant. So they can group them sequentially (without buffering the whole result set in memory like the regular LINQ to Objects `GroupBy`) with something like this (in pseudo-code):

```cs
var enumerator = query.GetEnumerator();
bool hasNext = enumerator.MoveNext();
while (hasNext)
{
    var aId = enumerator.Current["AId"]; // <-- here is where it is needed
    var aName = enumerator.Current["AName"];
    var bNames = new List<string>();
    do
    {
        bNames.Add(enumerator.Current["BName"]);
        hasNext = enumerator.MoveNext();
    }
    while (hasNext && aId == enumerator.Current["AId"]); // <-- as well here
    // ready to produce record for the consumer
    yield return new { Name = aName, BookNames = bNames };
}
```

Comment: Ok, got it. Thank you. So the use of `[a].[Id]` is justified. But as you yourself mentioned, `[b].[Id]` is redundant, so why does EF Core retrieve it in this case?

Comment: @Arad Bug/defect/missing optimization. We all do such things, especially when having deadlines and different priorities.

Answer (score 1):

Ivan Stoev explained why the first query returns the IDs. The *second* query is very different. While the first query returns one root object per author containing all the author's books, the second returns a flat list of objects. There's no need to know the IDs in this case. The equivalent starting from the `Authors` would be

```
var bookNames= from a in dbContext.Authors
               from b in a.Books
               select new {a.Name,BookNames=new {b.Name}};
```